# How do I filter this dataframe more efficiently? It currently is much too slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, optimization

I am working on a project that involves identifying groups of rows within a dataframe that share the same values for certain columns, then checking to see if the mean value for a certain KPI column for those rows is above a threshold. This involves repeatedly filtering a dataframe into a smaller dataframe by multiple column values. Below is the current function that handles the filtering.

```
def filter_df(df, cols, vals):
    """This function takes a dataframe, a list of columns, and a list of values.
     It returns a dataframe with only the rows that match the values for the columns."""
    temp_df = df
    for i in range(len(cols)):
        temp_df = temp_df[(temp_df[cols[i]] == vals[i])]
    return temp_df
```

[image: The %timeit results for this function]

I then implemented this for a static n = 6 columns as so, which cuts the speed roughly in half:

```
def filter_df(df, cols, vals):
    """This function takes a dataframe, a list of columns, and a list of values.
     It returns a dataframe with only the rows that match the values for the columns."""
    temp_df = df
    temp_df = temp_df[(temp_df[cols[0]] == vals[0]) & (temp_df[cols[1]] == vals[1]) & (temp_df[cols[2]] == vals[2]) & (temp_df[cols[3]] == vals[3]) & (temp_df[cols[4]] == vals[4]) & (temp_df[cols[5]] == vals[5])]
    return temp_df
```

[image: The %timeit results for this function]

My program involves running this function for every possible combination of values for every possible combination of n columns in an approximately 40 row dataset. Below is the form of the "main" function. Currently, there are ~3 million "groups" in the outer loop, with 240-1960 value combinations for each group in the inner loop.

```
def identify_clusters(df, KPI, n, KPI_threshhold):
    """This function takes in a dataframe, a KPI, a number of conditions, and a KPI threshhold.
    It returns a list of lists with each list of groups, the values list, and the ad_ids in the cluster."""
    groups = set_groups(df, n)
    output = []
    for i in range(len(groups)):
        vals_lst = set_values(groups[i], df)
        for comb in vals_lst:
            temp_df = filter_df(df, groups[i], comb)
            if temp_df[KPI].mean() > KPI_threshhold:
                output.append([groups[i], comb, temp_df['ad_id'].values])
    return output
```

My set_values function could also be a source of inefficiency, but I am not sure how to make it faster.

```
def set_values(group, df):
    """This function takes a list of columns and a dataframe. It returns a list of lists of all possible
     combinations of values for each column in the group in the dataframe."""
    vals_lst = []
    for col in group:
        vals_lst.append(list(df[col].dropna().unique()))
    output = list(itertools.product(*vals_lst))
    return output
```

[image: The %timeit output for this function]

I am observing that 1 iteration of the outer loop (analyzing a specific group of columns) takes between 0.5 and 2 seconds, which makes the completion of this code prohibitively long. **I am not sure whether the source of this inefficiency is in the filter_df function, in the identify_clusters function, both, or elsewhere.** I am aware that filtering through a dataframe with a for loop is typically substitutable for a vectorized function, but I am not sure how to implement this in filter_df when it will be taking an argument of a list of columns. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) use `line_profiler` to investigate what is your bottleneck. 2) (usually) it is bad to filter dataframe in a for loop as you did in first function. In your case it will be better to use this loop to find indices of rows you need, then filter dataframe only once using those indices

Comment: You probably dont need loops and filter. Could you share an example?

Comment: It's a little difficult to follow your logic. However, unless I have misunderstood, as you point out, your set_values method isn't ideal. You're repeatedly calling `list(df[col].dropna().unique())` but I don't think this ever changes, so if I'm right you're calculating this ~3million too many times; maybe create a dictionary of `col` -> `list(df[col].dropna().unique())` at the beginning and look up from this dictionary. Think there are some small gains you can make by using selection masks rather than filtering the dataframe. I would also be curious to know what you are doing with your output.